# E-Mail spammed while testing an e-mail chatbot

Tags: botframework

I have created a simple stock bot from the video. I have registered the bot for Skype, Facebook Messenger and E-Mail.

Skype, Facebook messenger works great and replies to the messages are received.

The problem which I have is with the E-Mail. When I send a E-Mail to the bot, for example, "Stock Price of MSFT" it sends an reply e-mail with the stock price and then it sends the same mail again and again without stopping until i remove the e-mail from the dev.botframework.com. Has anyone faced this issue. Is there any additional configuration which is needed to avoid this.

Eg: I sent a message to the bot e-mail saying "What is the stock price of msft" ?

I get a reply back with "Stock Price of msft is ... " from the bot. And the same reply e-mail I am getting continuously until I disable the E-MAIL Bot service..

MessageControl.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace StockBot2
{
    [BotAuthentication]
    public class MessagesController : ApiController
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// POST: api/Messages
        /// Receive a message from a user and reply to it
        /// </summary>
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
        {
            if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {
                ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));

                string StockRateString;
                StockLUIS StLUIS = await GetEntityFromLUIS(activity.Text);
                if (StLUIS.intents.Count() > 0)
                {
                    switch (StLUIS.intents[0].intent)
                    {
                        case "StockPrice":
                            StockRateString = await GetStock(StLUIS.entities[0].entity);
                            break;
                        case "StockPrice2":
                            StockRateString = await GetStock(StLUIS.entities[0].entity);
                            break;
                        default:
                            StockRateString = "Sorry, I am not getting you...";
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    StockRateString = "Sorry, I am not getting you...";
                }

                // return our reply to the user
                Activity reply = activity.CreateReply(StockRateString);
                await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
            }
            else
            {
                HandleSystemMessage(activity);
            }
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            return response;
        }

        private Activity HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
        {
            if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData)
            {
                // Implement user deletion here
                // If we handle user deletion, return a real message
            }
            else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
            {
                // Handle conversation state changes, like members being added and removed
                // Use Activity.MembersAdded and Activity.MembersRemoved and Activity.Action for info
                // Not available in all channels
            }
            else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate)
            {
                // Handle add/remove from contact lists
                // Activity.From + Activity.Action represent what happened
            }
            else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Typing)
            {
                // Handle knowing tha the user is typing
            }
            else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Ping)
            {
            }

            return null;
        }

        private async Task<string> GetStock(string StockSymbol)
        {
            double? dblStockValue = await YahooBot.GetStockRateAsync(StockSymbol);
            if (dblStockValue == null)
            {
                return string.Format("This \"{0}\" is not an valid stock symbol", StockSymbol);
            }
            else
            {
                return string.Format("Stock Price of {0} is {1}", StockSymbol, dblStockValue);
            }
        }

        private static async Task<StockLUIS> GetEntityFromLUIS(string Query)
        {
            Query = Uri.EscapeDataString(Query);
            StockLUIS Data = new StockLUIS();
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                string RequestURI = "https://api.projectoxford.ai/luis/v1/application?id=1c85d9de-7c8d-4ceb-ba11-860f02ce911b&subscription-key=fe48030063c6458587138c4dcd258737&q=" + Query;
                HttpResponseMessage msg = await client.GetAsync(RequestURI);

                if (msg.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var JsonDataResponse = await msg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StockLUIS>(JsonDataResponse);
                }
            }
            return Data;
        }
    }
}
```

YahooBot.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;

namespace StockBot2
{
    public class YahooBot
    {
        public static async Task<double?> GetStockRateAsync(string StockSymbol)
        {
            try
            {
                string ServiceURL = $"http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s={StockSymbol}&f=sl1d1nd";
                string ResultInCSV;
                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
                    ResultInCSV = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(ServiceURL).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
                var FirstLine = ResultInCSV.Split('\n')[0];
                var Price = FirstLine.Split(',')[1];
                if (Price != null && Price.Length >= 0)
                {
                    double result;
                    if (double.TryParse(Price, out result))
                    {
                        return result;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                //handle your exception here  
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (‘**why isn't this code working?**’) must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hope the above example helps

Comment: It does *not*. There's still no code.

Comment: So basically you're saying your code is doing stuff that you don't want. Now you want us to tell you what is wrong with that code, but you won't show it to us?

Comment: Hi. This is a sample app which just reads the stock value from yahoo api and displays it to the user.  When the user sends to bot "Stock Price of MSFT" it replies back "Stock Price is ..". This all logic works fine with bot emulator, skype and facebook emulator. Not with email. I will add code

Comment: Added Code for reference

Comment: To respond to your question, "has anyone faced this issue" - I did, and couldn't solve it either. The bot kept sending emails until I removed the email credentials.